# How do I exit out of my do while loop? c++

Tags: c++, while-loop

Ok before anyone bashes me, I checked every forum to try to help me solve this problem but unfortunately cannot solve it. Can someone point to the right direction to solve this? I am trying to exit this do while loop immediately when inputting the value -1. For example I want the output to look like this when I input -1:

Enter the expected number of hours charging: 
//user enters -1
Exiting...

```
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    float hour;
    float Network1, Network2, Network3;

    do {
        cout << "Enter the expected number of hours charging:" << endl;
        cin >> hour;

    Network1= (1 * hour) + 10;
    Network2= (2.50 * hour);
    Network3 = (0.50 * hour) + 20;

        cout << "Your expected costs are: " << endl;
        cout << "Network 1: $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << Network1 << endl;
        cout << "Network 2: $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << Network2 << endl;
        cout << "Network 3: $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << Network3 << endl;

        if(Network1 < Network2 && Network1 < Network3){
            cout << "The lowest cost network is $" << Network1 << endl;
        }
        else if (Network2 < Network1 && Network2 < Network3){
            cout << "The lowest cost network is $" << Network2 << endl;
        }
        else{
            cout << "The lowest cost network is $" << Network3 << endl;
        }
    }
    while (hour != -1) ;

    cout << "Exiting..." << endl;

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: A google search for 'c++ exit while' should be suffice to give you an answer

Answer (score 2):

There is two ways:

1. You can check input right after read

```
cin >> hour;
if (hour == -1) {
    break;
}
```

2. You can use `while` loop and read value twice. First one before the first iteration and the second in the end

```
cout << "Enter the expected number of hours charging:" << endl;
cin >> hour;
while (hour != -1) {
    // ...
    cout << "Enter one more value:" << endl;
    cin >> hour;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic ways of doing this, the neanderthal way and the cromagnon way.

The neanderthal way;

```
for(;;) { 
   cout << "Enter the expected number of hours charging:" << endl;
   cin >> hour;
   if (!cin || hour == -1) break;
   ...
```

The cromagnon way:

```
while (std::cout << "Enter the expected number of hours charging: \n" &&
            std::cin >> hour &&
            hour! = -1) {
   ...
```

Methods that do not involve checking of `cin` properly belong to pithecanthrops.